# Rails 3.0 ORM agnostic admin plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activescaffold

Hey fellow Rail-ists, do know any equivalent of ActiveScaffold but being ORM agnostic or at least for Mongoid?

Comment: Isn't Mongoid already compatible with ActiveRecord and thus just works?

Comment: No it just conforms with ActiveModel, ActiveScaffold though is tied to ActiveRecord

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

Comment: Seems like rails_admin is still not quite ORM agnostic. [https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/105](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/105)

Comment: ActiveAdmin is tracking this as well, with a few patches available for anyone who wants to ride the edge. https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/26